# convert vertically listed strings of a text file to horizontal format

Tags: c#

I have a text file "Test 2.txt" with the below format:

```
string1
string2
string3
string4
string5
string6
string7
string8
string9
...and so on...
```

I would like to convert it to text file "Test.txt" with below format:

```
string1,string2,string3
string4,string5,string6
string7,string8,string9
...and so on...
```

My code at the moment is below:

```
string line;
string DatabaseFullPath = @"C:\Test2.xsr";

using (var file = new StreamReader(DatabaseFullPath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    int count = File.ReadLines(DatabaseFullPath).Count();

    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        count++;
        if (count % 3 == 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.txt"))
            {
                writetext.WriteLine(line + '\n');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.txt"))
            {
                writetext.Write(line + ',');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the StreamWriter is just overwriting each string "line" with another string "line" but I am not sure about it.

Comment: You don't say what is wrong with your code?

Comment: But it is full of errors! Why are you outputting `'\n'` with `WriteLine` - do you want to double space? Why are you using `ReadLines` and also reading line by line? Why are you initializing `count` to the number of lines in the file? Why are you opening your output file everytime you output to it?

Comment: Hi NetMage. Sorry if the question is unclear. I have edited my question. the Writeline is Write before but I can't get it writing all that is why I changed it to Writeline. I am a newbie and needs an experts advise on this. The count is for me to catch the 3rd line of the text file (count % 3 == 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string DatabaseFullPath = @"C:\Test2.xsr";

using (var file = new StreamReader(DatabaseFullPath, Encoding.UTF8)) {
    using (StreamWriter writetext = new StreamWriter(@"D:\Test.txt")) {
        int count = 0;
        string line;
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
            if (++count % 3 == 0)
                writetext.WriteLine(line);
            else
                writetext.Write(line + ',');
        }
    }
}
```